# some problem while using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I have some problem while using biblatex.I add package like this:

```
\usepackage[hyperref=true,backend=biber,style=alphabetic,backref=true,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

and it's my bib file:

```
@book{Heath,
title="A history of Greek Mathematics,Vol 1",
author="Thomas Heath",
publisher="Oxford University Press",
year="1921"
}
```

then I cite it like this:

```
but not other tool\cite{Heath}
```

when I compile with xelatex and bibtex,texstudio say there is some problem:[image]

I don't know how to fix it.Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. You should be running biber, not bibtex.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as @Mico gave the best answer in his comment

Comment: You'll probably want to configure your editor to run Biber for you. That can be done as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what Biber does.

Comment: Thanks all!And I find that I have to rename filename from Chinese to English to use biber.